# How do I use the uninstall script that comes with Git to uninstall Git on my Mac?

Tags: git

It is causing conflict with my older Mac Lion and I need to uninstall and reinstall a later version after I update my MAC.  I tried to uninstall it by copying and pasting the uninstall script into the Command line and I got a whole bunch od sodu warnings and a request for a password.  What password is it asking for?  The one to my computer?  I am very new to this, can someone please give me the exact script or code I can cut and paste to uninstall this and move on?  Again I am very new, and started learning this week. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Probably sudo password. check this out.

http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht1528